# Unity初心者が取り組むべきチュートリアルを教えてください

Tags: unity3d

Unityのコミュニティは日々成長しており、初心者も日々増えています。
TipsなどもWeb上には日々増え続けていますが、初心者がまず求めるのは
「Unityの扱い方が分かるチュートリアル」または「自分が作りたいジャンルのゲームのチュートリアル」だと思われます。しかし、記事が増え続けているだけに、検索してヒットするのはたくさんあるチュートリアルのほんの一部だと思います。チュートリアルを探せる/告知できる場があると良いかもしれないと思ったので投稿させていただきました。

ということで、皆さんの知っている/連載している**日本語の**チュートリアルをジャンルに分類して教えて頂けませんか？
追加で書き込むか、最初の回答（コミュニティWiki設定）に書き加えて頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: こちらのような「参考文献集」のような質問について日本語版ではどうするか、[メタで議題としてあげました](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1384/30)。英語版SOにならって参考文献はタグWikiに書くのがいいかなと個人的には思っていますが、どうでしょう。メタの方にご意見いただければうれしいです。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: [どんな質問がリスト質問？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1382/3054) にて示されている「リスト質問」にあたります。実際に「自己宣伝（またはステマ) やリンクだけの回答が多くなりがち」という現象が見られます。

Answer (score 3):

## Unityについて

- Unity Basic 【公式】
  http://japan.unity3d.com/developer/document/tutorial/basic/
- Tutorials 【動画】【公式】【字幕有】
  http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules
- 【入門編】世界よ、これが本当の Unity 講座だ（１）
  http://developers.mobage.jp/blog/true-unity-course
- 【入門編】世界よ、これが本当の Unity 講座だ（２）
  http://developers.mobage.jp/blog/true-unity-course2

## アクション

#### 3D

#### 2D

## シューティング

#### 3D

- 【Unity】超入門3DゲームBlockShot!!
  http://realisapp.com/unity3d/%e3%80%90unity%e3%80%91%e8%b6%85%e5%85%a5%e9%96%803d%e3%82%b2%e3%83%bc%e3%83%a0blockshot/

#### 2D

- 2Dシューティング【公式】
  http://japan.unity3d.com/developer/document/tutorial/2d-shooting-game/

## RPG

#### 3D

#### 2D

## シミュレーション

#### 3D

#### 2D

## アドベンチャー

#### 3D

#### 2D

## パズル

#### 3D

- はじめてのUnity【公式】（ブロック崩し）
  http://japan.unity3d.com/developer/document/tutorial/my-first-unity/

#### 2D

- Unityでブロック崩し
   http://am1tanaka.hatenablog.com/archive/category/Unity%E3%81%A7%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E5%B4%A9%E3%81%97

## その他

- テラシュールブログ　「ゲーム　作り方」
  http://tsubakit1.hateblo.jp/entry/20140218/1392651856

#### 3D

#### 2D

### 言語

- Unityで覚えるC#
  http://www.slideshare.net/lucifuges/unityc
- C# によるプログラミング入門 ++C++; //未確認飛行 C
  http://ufcpp.net/study/csharp/
- LINQ to GameObjectによるUnityでのLINQの活用
  http://neue.cc/2014/11/11_482.html

※この投稿はコミュニティWiki設定ですので信用度が100あれば自由に編集できます。

Answer (score 0):

私のサイトの記事[「Unity入門にオススメ！初心者向けのチュートリアルサイト6選」](http://programming-study.com/trouble/unity-tutorial/)より、おすすめのチュートリアルを紹介します。

ある程度難易度順に並べているので、迷った際は上から辿っていくことをおすすめします。

### 初めてのUnity

http://tutorial.unity3d.jp/

名前から見ても分かる通り、本当に初めての方でもUnityの概要がわかる内容になっています。まず、はじめに球転しゲームのチュートリアルを行うことをおすすめします。2Dシューティングの方のチュートリアルは少し難易度が高い部分もあるので、Unityに慣れてからでも問題ありません。

### Unity-OpenBook

http://openbook4.me/projects/161

電子書籍を共同で編集できるプラットフォーム「OpenBook」の「Unity入門」です。初めてのUnityの球転しゲームより少し難易度が高めになっています。これを理解できるようになれば、とりあえずグーグル検索をすればある程度のゲームは作れるようになります。

### ひよこのたまご

http://hiyotama.hatenablog.com/archive/category/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%88%E3%81%93%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9

初心者用のチュートリアルより一歩踏み込んだ内容を紹介している個人ブログです。アイテムを取った時の処理など最初に取り組むチュートリアルというより、ゲームを作り込む際に参考になるチュートリアルと言えます。また、中級者向けの記事もたくさんあるので、Unityの技術がある程度ついてからもお世話になることが多くなると思います。

### Unity本家動画教材

http://unity3d.com/jp/learn/tutorials

Unity公式サイトの動画教材です。元々ある完成プロジェクトを解説していくような形の動画になっています。特筆すべきはその完成プロジェクトのクオリティの高さです。自分でもこんなゲームを作れるようになると感じると、Unityへのモチベーションがグングン上がること間違いなしです。ただ、字幕があるものもありますが英語で説明されているのが難点です。

### Unity3DでFPSつくってみるチュートリアル

http://loumo.jp/wp/archive/20130402230827/

UnityでFPSを作成するチュートリアルです。これを進められるようになってくると、Unityの高性能さをつくづく感じるようになってきます。FPSが大好き！作ってみたいという方は是非やってみることをおすすめします。

### 【入門編】世界よ、これが本当のUnity講座だ

http://developers.mobage.jp/blog/true-unity-course

これはmobageのデベロッパーがブログとして書かれた記事なのですが、とてもためになることが書いてあります。Unityの技術的な内容よりも、Unityとは何か、ゲームエンジンとしての位置付けなど、本質的な部分へと迫っていく内容になっています。ある程度Unityの技術が上がって伸び悩む時期にこの記事を読むと、理解力がさらに高まり、新しい成長が期待出来ます。また、最終的に「既存アセットのユニティちゃんを使って3Dの障害避けゲーム」を作ることができます。

Comment: [meta]でこの投稿についての[ディスカッション](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2400/15185)が投稿されていますので、Morio様の意見もお聞きできたら幸いです。

Comment: 上記ディスカッションでの意見を受け、各記事へのリンクを追加し、全体の構成を少し変更しました。ジャンルに分類されていない、既存のコミュニティWiki回答を使うべきでは、という点については解決していませんが、とりあえず。（もしMorioさんの意に反した編集になっていましたら、お手数ですが[編集履歴](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/31838/revisions)からロールバックしていただくか、改めて編集をお願いします。）